# 3 monitors without VGA port on a laptop

Tags: multiple-monitors, vga, external-display, dvi, dell-vostro

per the subject, I don't think I'm doing this right. I'm getting conflicting info from many different people in person. I have one HDMI port and one video card on a laptop. IBM ideapad 3. I'd like 3 monitors. I have one connected already through the adapter and a DVI-DVI male-male cord. my 2 externals are dells and they both have VGA and DI ports on them.  the rest of the info is in the attached images. can someone give me a boost here please? I have looked at many other threads here and learned quite a bit but am confused based on what humans in person are telling me.  thank you.

[image]

[image: 3rdMonitorError]

[image: deviceManagerUSBitems]

[image: displaySettings]

[image: DVIchord]

Comment: I've brightened up your first image, but I still can't tell what plugs are on the side opf the puter. "one HDMI port and one video card" doesn't really make much sense. Can you clarify what outputs are available? that last plug won't convert to VGA because it's a DVI-I, no analog component.

Comment: the outputs that are avail are:

- 3 usb ports
- 1 hdmi port
- 1 power plug
- headphone jack

that's it.  what does 1 hdmi port and one video card not make any sense?  and are you saying that external mons cannot work with DVI cords?  just VGAs?  thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to handle this. I expect the best is docking station with the ports you need. It will plug into a single USB port. You can also get direct converters that will go from a USB port to VGA. You could also use one that converts HDMI to VGA

Comment: i will look into docking station.  thank you so much!  I think that is only way to go really.  from everyone I talk to, it seems like that is best.

Comment: You are welcome. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers